# Industrial product IEC 61000-3-2 compliance

Tags: standard, harmonics, compliance, iec

I have a question related to IEC 61000-3-2 standard for current harmonics limits.

I am working on an industrial product rated for 500W that connects to the grid (220VAC).

The standard states that there is no limit for "Professional equipment (not intended for sale to the general public) with rated power greater than 1kW. ".

I found a flowchat in the standard guidelines and it shows that the standard is not applicable for professionnal equipment Power rated less than 1kW, which is the contrary of the statement above.

[image]

My question is:

-For a 500W industrial product, do I need to comply with 61000-3-2 (therefore I would probably need a PFC).

Thank you.

Comment: When you have a standard and supplemental material that are in conflict, it's always the standard which is right. That's because it's the standard.